# How to size down a vector shape in Sketch 3 without losing quality?

Tags: image, vector-graphics, sketch-3

I have been trying to resize a logo and make it fit into my navigation bar, but the problem is that it started off as an image from someone at 3932 X 1712px. I traced it with the vector tool, but I need to resize the entire logo as 108 X 47px. Every time I scale the vector down that much, it totally loses clarity and looks extremely pixelated. I tried resizing a little down then exporting that and then resizing a little more, but that also eventually loses quality. I even resized it down a little then vectorized that, but even the vector lines were pixelated. Would love to use this logo in my website and this is annoying. Help!

Comment: Could it be the number of vector points I'm adding?

Answer (score 0):

- Open Vector image in Photoshop
- Go to file menu > Save for Web
- Use Original image to save
- Set height-47, width-108
- Save image in .png format

Try it, it can be work